# How to vertical grid with sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I can't to solve a hitch for a second day.

How can I make `left_side` grow with `right_side` if a text string is added in it?

And also how to make the column go no more than 4 cells, or after a certain height, there was a transfer to the right?

And lastly, after adding `float: left" "sortable"` stop working properly...

Assist with the decision, I'm a backend developer, in the front-end is not strong, but the task was thrown together with the backend.

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/veWZKr/)

Comment: ?? not too sure i understand, but height and display might be in the way.  did you mean to apply the grid display to the list and not the wrapper ?  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/boYrVp

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, one person helped with decision: codepen.io/iamevg/pen/LzOjpM